# How do I use a variable to assign a css id in an html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, erb

I have a class in a .html.erb view file that I want to give an id based on a variable.

I want to do something like this:

```
<ul id="#{store}">
```

Where `store` is a variable containing the string "store1".

I want this to yield an ul like this: `<ul id=store1>`, but I get `<ul id=#{store}>` instead.

Do I need to create a helper to help facilitate this or is there some syntax I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul id="<%= yourvariable %>">
```